# Как работать с SetDIBitsToDevice?

Tags: c++, winapi

В программе, в которую я хочу внедрить `SetDIBitsToDevice`, используется двойная буферизация, на конечный `HDC` выводиться всё с помощью ф-ии `BitBlt`. Естественно проблемы с производительностью. Раньше, при изучении, пропустил мимо `SetDIBitsToDevice`, теперь понял что она, видимо то что мне нужно.

Итак, если я правильно понял алгоритм таков:

**Создаём массив, который будет нашей "матрицей" -  создаём `BITMAPINFO`, заполняем - "рисуем" в нашей "матрице" - вызываем `SetDIBitsToDevice`.**

Код ниже выполнятся правильно, видим розовый фон и чёрный квадрат.

```
    BITMAPINFO bif;
    ZeroMemory(&bif, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));

    bif.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bif);
    
    RGBQUAD *im = new RGBQUAD[r.right*r.bottom];

    for (int i(0); i < r.right*r.bottom; i++)
    {
        im[i].rgbBlue = 255;
        im[i].rgbRed = 255;
        im[i].rgbGreen = 0;
    }

    for (int i(0); i < 200; i++)
        for (int ii(0); ii < 200; ii++)
    {
        if (r.right*i + ii < r.right*r.bottom)
        {
            im[r.right*i + ii].rgbBlue = 0;
            im[r.right*i + ii].rgbRed = 0;
            im[r.right*i + ii].rgbGreen = 0;
        }
    }

    bif.bmiHeader.biHeight = -r.bottom;
    bif.bmiHeader.biWidth = r.right;
    bif.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = ((bif.bmiHeader.biWidth * 24 + 31)& ~31) / 8 * bif.bmiHeader.biHeight;
    bif.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bif.bmiHeader.biBitCount = sizeof(RGBQUAD)*8;

    SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc, 0, 0, r.right, r.bottom, 0, 0, 0, r.bottom, im, &bif, DIB_PAL_COLORS);
    
    delete[] im;
```

Но писать свои `Rectangle` `Ellipse` и т.д. времени нету, да и я о сглаживании молчу. Значит нужно использовать **GDI** и **GDI+**. Каков алгоритм в этом случае(если я не прав, то поправьте):

**Создаём совместный ДС, и битмап - рисуем там - создаём массив, который будет нашей "матрицей" -  создаём `BITMAPINFO`, заполняем, с помощью SetDIBits - вызываем `SetDIBitsToDevice`.**

Код ниже не выполнятся правильно, просто белый фон

```
    tagPAINTSTRUCT ps;
    hdc=BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    HDC hdcc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP bm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, r.right, r.bottom);
    SelectObject(hdcc, bm);
    
    HBRUSH hb = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
    SelectObject(hdcc, hb);
    Rectangle(hdcc, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    DeleteObject(hb);
    
    BITMAPINFO bif;
    ZeroMemory(&bif, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));

    bif.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bif);
    
    RGBQUAD *im = new RGBQUAD[r.right*r.bottom];

    SetDIBits(hdcc, bm, 0, r.bottom, im, &bif, DIB_PAL_COLORS);

    SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc, 0, 0, r.right, r.bottom, 0, 0, 0, r.bottom, im, &bif, DIB_PAL_COLORS);
    
    delete[] im;

    DeleteObject(bm);
    DeleteDC(hdcc);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

1)На МСДН написано, что нельзя в `SetDIBits` передавать использующийся в данный момент HBITMAP, но как тогда в него рисовать?

2)Возможно я не полностью\не правильно заполняю `HBITMAP`. В одном из примеров видел что `SetDIBits` вызывается дважды, в первый раз в качестве указателя на массив передаётся 0, как объяснял автор, именно так заполняется `HBITMAPINFO`.

Answer (score 1):

Походу всё из-за того, что на часах было час ночи. Вся проблема была в том, что я для конвертации `HBITMAP` использовал **SetDIBits**, a надо было **GetDIBits**. И да, вызвать надо дважды. Вот полностью рабочий пример:

```
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &r);
    tagPAINTSTRUCT ps;
    hdc=BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    HDC hdcc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP bm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, r.right, r.bottom), sec = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, r.right, r.bottom);
    SelectObject(hdcc, bm);

    //ТОДО: код прорисовки
    HBRUSH hb = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    SelectObject(hdcc, hb);
    Rectangle(hdcc, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    DeleteObject(hb);
    //

    BITMAPINFO bif;
    ZeroMemory(&bif, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    //Эти поля нужно зполнять вручную
    bif.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bif.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 4*8;
    bif.bmiHeader.biWidth = r.right;
    bif.bmiHeader.biHeight = r.bottom;

    GetDIBits(hdcc, bm, 0, 0, 0, &bif, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    RGBQUAD *im = new RGBQUAD[r.right*r.bottom];

    GetDIBits(hdcc, bm, 0, r.bottom, im, &bif, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc, 0, 0, r.right, r.bottom, 0, 0, 0, r.bottom, im, &bif, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    delete[] im;

    DeleteObject(bm);
    DeleteDC(hdcc);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

Как всегда пришлось перерыть 300 форумов, мсднов и стэковерфлоувов...

Comment: Так и не понял, зачем Вам тут нужен был `SetDIBitsToDevice`. Он используется только в случае, если Вам нужно отобразить растр из памяти, двойная буферизация тут ни при чем.

Comment: @mega, я прочитал что она быстрее(оказалось нет), чем `BitBlt`

Comment: Она быстрее только в том случае, если Вы делаете какие-то поточечные манипуляции в памяти, т.е. она обгонит сочетание `GetPixel/BitBlt`, но Вы здесь ничего такого не используете, рисуете теми же GDI-инструментами (CreateSolidBrush/SelectObject/Rectangle), т.е. ни как не используете прямой доступ к памяти растра.

Comment: @mega, может тогда посоветуете не Gdi  инструменты? Или надо писать свои?

Comment: Вы бы лучше описали в вопросе задачу, для начала. Или задайте новый вопрос. Нет волшебной функции, которая решает проблемы с производительностью. Чтобы подобрать инструмент, надо понять задачу.

Comment: @mega, да я пишу что-то вроде своего рендера, всё слишком обобщёно. Но я уже нашёл другой способ оптимизации. Спасибо